# sql server 2005 express space needed to create index formula

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

What is the formula to figure out how much space an index will need to be created ?

IMPORTANT: We are using sql server express 2005. So 4GB is the limit. Hence this question.
Unrestricted Autogrow of log files is not an option. t-sql psuedo code below will explain further.

```
int spaceNeeded = 
  FN_COMPUTE_SPACE_NEEDED_TO_CREATE_UNCLUSTERED_INDEX(MyTableName, MyColumnName)
```

It's the one function above that I am stuck at while coding this stored proc
I think I can handle all the below with info available on msdn etc.

```
While(GetDBSpaceAvailable() < spaceNeeded )
{
    purge some data (go thru all tables and delete data logically)
}

create the index we need
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NonClustered_MyTable] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(   [MyColumn] ASC
)
```

Any pointers appreciated in this regards. Hoping this is a repeat but could not find anything when I searched.
thank you

**UPDATE**: Solution that worked for me uses Aaron's suggestion. (additional 1.2X over and above the space the index occupies now). So basically I purge oldest data until space available is 1.2 to 1.5x over and above the current index size reported by **sp_spaceused tablename**. Then create the index.

Comment: You say "Unrestricted autogrow of log files is not an option." I'm not a big Express user, but are you sure that log file size is part of the calculation? (I haven't run any tests but I'm pretty sure it's not.) Are you sure this is relevant to your problem anyway? Are you seeing massive log usage, data file expansion, or both when you run this operation?

Comment: thanks Aaron and JNK. i will check the error message I get when I try to create an index on a full or almost full express db. Will post error back here soon. We use express db in production to keep costs down. The logic purges older data when it maxes out. We have a situation where we need to upgrade our express db's with an index for some reporting app and thats the background.

Comment: Here is Microsoft's user friendly error message :) when I try to create the index Msg 1105, Level 17, State 2, Line 1
Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  422212493901824' in database 'MyDB' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full.
Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size limit is only per database. Have you considered putting some of your junk, static or at least less volatile data into a separate database? You can create synonyms to make it so that the code doesn't realize some of the data is in its own 4GB space. All on one instance you'd be hard-pressed to notice any performance difference by splitting it up, the biggest problem would be backup consistency as you'd be backing up the data separately. But it would be one way to avoid your index space requirements.

Also, instead of using this old version of SQL Server 2005 Express, why not move to the most recent released version (SQL Server 2008 R2), where you have 6 more GB to play with (database size is limited to 10 GB instead of 4 GB). In addition you get some new features, T-SQL syntax and performance benefits.

Comment: Yes. We are in the process of upgrading to 2008 express. I am surprised there is no formula or general guidelines to compute space needed to create an index given the current size of the database, size of table on which index is being created, columns and column size of index being created on and available free space etc...

Comment: The conventional wisdom to rebuild an index is you'll need an additional 1.2X over and above the space the index occupies now. However, as JNK points out, this can vary greatly depending on the data that's actually used, fill factor, changes to the index... so no, there is no magic math that will tell you what is needed until you actually need to do it.

Comment: ok. If trial and error is what it takes than I will get some coffee and dive right in. thx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to know for certain.

It's not just the index that is created, it also creates a b-tree used to parse the index leaf nodes, as well as supporting statistics.

Both those factors are affected by the distribution of your data values, selectivity, etc.

There are additional options that affect space used like fill factor, included fields, etc.

Also it would be a real challenge regardless of the factors above to calculate this for `varchar` or `nvarchar` fields, since the length (and therefore space used) varies row to row.

**It makes more sense just to get a SQL Server License** instead of putting in the hundreds of man-hours it would take to make this accurate and deal with recoding when it inevitably had an issue.

Comment: +1 the way to find out how much space you need to perform such a task, is to perform the task. Instead of trying to decide how much data to purge based on how much space you need, purge all the data you don't need. If you still don't have room, then you need to scale out or up.

Comment: Buy a SQL Server license !! Take a look at their pricing. Forget the man hours. If we a license for every sale of our product , we may close shop and I will have to go back to India and be software coolie again. http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/pricing.aspx  Google for coolie :-)

Comment: It's tough to scoff at a suggestion when you didn't make it clear in your question that you are distributing Express with software, rather than just using a copy of the database in-house.

Comment: Didnt mean to scoff or anything. Apologies. Agree my question was not clear. thx